# Can you illustrate the following with the help of a graph?

Tags: data-visualization, survival, censoring

Can you please help me visualise the following situation using a graph or anything?
Also, where does the "life time" start from and where does it end?

> The data set may contain both left and right censored observations.
>   A psychiatrist collected data to determine the age at which children have
>   learned to perform a particular task. The **lifetime** was the time the child
>   has taken to learn to perform the task from date of birth. Those children
>   who already knew how to perform the task, when he arrived at the village
>   were left censored and those who did not learn the task even by the time
>   he departed were right-censored observations.

Source: Jayant Deshpande's "Life Time Data: Statistical Models and Methods"

Two declarations:
1. This is a theoretical question, not a programming question.
2. This is not a homework question, although it may appear that way.

I am currently studying Survival Analysis and I'm a newb at it, so the questions may appear silly. Please bear with me.

Comment: There is another subtle right-censoring case as well: children who were learning the task when the psychiatrist arrived (and finished before he departed).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your investigator is interested in something like the [Flynn effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flynn_effect) and whether people born more recently are on average more intelligent that those born earlier.

Here is some simulated data, where something takes about $10$ years to learn from birth (standard deviation of $2$) and where the investigator observes those who learn this thing between $2005$ and $2010$.  In the simulation there is no effect from birth date but the observed data might suggest that there is:

[image]

The next picture shows the censored data but it is not totally clear what is happening

[image]

but if we change the variables shown then the censorship is more obvious. If there was an effect of later birthdate reducing learning times then this should also mean that learning times should also be falling on average with learning dates, and this simulated data does not seem to suggest that

[image]